# SQS Trigger Lambda, with FileName in S3 for text extraction

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, text-extraction

I have a use case, I have a list of pdf files stored in S3 Bucket, I have listed them and push them to SQS for Text Extraction, Created one Lambda for processing those files by providing bucket information and TextExtraxtion Information of AWS.

The issue is, Lambda is getting Timeout, as SQS trigger multiple lambda instance of all files and all of them waiting for Text Extract Service.

Lambda to trigger one by one, for all SQS message(FileName) so that Timeout does not occur, As we do have a limit for accessing AWS TextExtract

Comment: how many files do you process per lambda instance?

Comment: also what is your lambda timeout?

Comment: Lambda timeout I set to Max 15 minutes.

Comment: @Horatiu , there could be 100  files or more, that need to be process, providing file name in sqs.

Comment: Did you tried setting `batch size` to 1? See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html

Comment: This will make lambda to pick single message at once from SQS, but my concern is,  multiple Lambda is getting created as soon as I push multiple messages to SQS.

Answer (score 0):

Processing 100+ files is a time consuming task, I would suggest taking no more than 10 files per Lambda execution.

Use SQS with Lambda as an event source.
https://dzone.com/articles/amazon-sqs-as-an-event-source-to-aws-lambda-a-deep

Comment: For each file, one lambda instance is getting created as I am using sqs for triggering lambda. My concern lies with those lambda waiting for text extract to process.

Comment: The text extract should not take that much. How large is a file?

Comment: Files could be till 30 Mb or more

Comment: the maybe considering one file per lambda, or even split that file beforehand

Comment: That is what I am using, by taking batch size 1, but still, multiple lambda instance is getting created, and they process those files.